# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Terminal text looking glitched

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The desktop environment I am using is GNOME Shell. Once, when I launched the terminal, it opened up slower than usual and the text in it looked different. There are weird spaces between the text and the text looks jagged:

[image: There are weird spaces between the text and the text looks jagged.]

Please help me fix this issue. It looks even more terrible when there is a lot of text in the terminal and is ruining my overall user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in `gnome-terminal` should be used a [monospace font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). Apparently for some reason your default monospace font is changed within the settings. To change the default value (system wide) you can use the tool `dconf-editor`. Install it by the command:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then open the application and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and find the setting `monospace-font-name`. The first result should be in `org`>`gnome`>`interface` as it shown on the following picture. If the option line is bold that means this is not the default value. Select it and use the button <kbd>Set to Default</kbd> in the down right corner.

[image]

*Currently I do not have Gnome Shell installed, but probably these settings are the same as in Unity.*

If the above does'n help you can check your current `gnome-terminal` profile options. Open `gnome-terminal` and in the `Edit` menu choice `Profile Preferences`. In the bottom of the `General` tab have an `Custom font` option. Untick it if it is ticked (as it is shown on the picture below), or choice your desired monospace font. Within Unity this is "Ubuntu Mono Regular" with size 13.

[image]